# Jquery issue Undefined is not a function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have applied a datepicker in my script but I am facing an issue in it.
Whatever version of jquery I apply it said "Undefined is not a function" and datepicker not runs. My site is LIVE please help me in that case,

What I am missing.

http://mountainsportshaus.com/skirental/step-1.php

Error Screen Shot:
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0a848v1oe9

My jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="manager/calendar_popup/jquery.datepick.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(function() {



$('#date_start,#date_end').datepick({
    onSelect: customRange, 
    showOn: 'both', buttonImageOnly: true, buttonImage: 'manager/calendar_popup/calendar.gif'}); 
 function customRange(dateStr, date) { 
    if (this.id == 'date_start') { 
        $('#date_end').datepick('option', 'minDate', date); 
    } 
    else { 
        $('#date_start').datepick('option', 'maxDate', date); 
    } 
}

});

</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question.

Comment: You've posted 12 previous questions. The requirement that the code and other information related to your question be **in** the question (not just linked) shouldn't be news to you.

Answer (score 0):

Look at their demo, they incuded this js file

```
<script src="js/jquery.plugin.js"></script>
```

It seems like the datepicker require that to work.

Comment: Can you please explain this question? I did not get you what you are saying?

Comment: The date picker lib you used (in this demo http://keith-wood.name/datepickBasics.html) require another js file http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.plugin.js